# Pasar codigo de Python a html

Tags: html, python

He realizado un predictor de tiempo con python y sklearn. Quisiera capturar los datos ("humidity" y "wind") mediante un formulario html(uso de input), luego comprobarlos en python y finalmente retornar la respuesta en el archivo de html (el dato sobre si está lloviendo o no). Había pensado hacerlo escribiendo un documento de texto y hacer que python lo lea, pero no sé cómo se podría hacer eso. A continuación, el código python, ¿cómo podría implementarlo en html?

```
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Weather informartion. [ humidity , wind]

def weatherprediction (humidity,wind)

X = [[88 , 125 ] ,[23,15] ,[79,200] , [44,45],[68,111],[35,30] ,[22,10],[38,10],[39,150] , [97,20]]

Y = ['Rain','Dont rain','Rain','Rain','Rain','Dont rain','Dont rain','Dont rain','Dont rain','Rain']

clf = clf.fit(X,Y)   #The program learn how the informantion is related

prediction = clf.predict([[humidity,wind]])

print(prediction)
```

Comment: Hola David, posiblemente la pregunta a no ser que se concretara mucho, no deje de ser una pregunta basada en opiniones. Sea como sea, falta mucha información relevante,  por ejemplo ¿Cómo sirves ese "html generado"?¿Dónde va a ejecutarse ese código?¿Quién y cómo va a usar la app?¿Cuantos peticiones concurrentes esperarías? Puedes conseguir lo que quieres empezando por SimpleHTTPServer de la biblioteca estándar, pasando por los múltiples micro-frameworks  web que hay para Python (Flask, Bottle, CherryPy, Dash, ...),  frameworks (Django, Web2py, pyramid, TurboGears, ...),  CGI/WSGI, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo utilizar el framework Django (1), que permite conectar Python con HTML. DJANGO trabaja por defecto con mysqli, pero tu lo puedes conectar con la base de datos de tu preferencia. Revisa el manual adjunto en las referencias

Podrías considerar el siguiente modelo lógico para la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas tablas estarían representadas en la carpeta "modelos" de DJANGO. Los valores de la variable "x" y la variable "y" los obtendrías de la base de datos, luego haces el entrenamiento con "fit", la predicción con "predict" y el dato resultante lo devuelves mediante el sistema de plantillas de DJANGO.

Referencias:

(1) Manual de DJANGO 2.0. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.0/intro/tutorial01/